# Let the sequence $x_{n} \geq 0 $ $ \forall $ $n\geq N $, where $ N\geq i$, prove that the limit of $x_n \geq 0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Is it sufficient to assume that $L<0$. Then say that if all $x_n \geq 0$ this statement cannot be correct. So $L \geq 0$

Comment: What is $i$? And what if $x_n = 0$ for all $n$, then the limit is not greater than zero.

Comment: Sorry, $i$ is the beginning index of the sequence, generally 0/1. The question says $ L \geq 0 $

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction if my proof is flawed?

Comment: You should distinguish carefully between "$>0$" and "$\geq 0$". They mean different things. The proof mentioned in the title is impossible as stated, since the limit need not be strictly positive as the terms of the sequence are not strictly positive themselves.

Comment: That was an error in typing, my apologies, I can see how it changes the question completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inner telepat guessed that the problem formulates like this:

*Let the  sequence $x_n$ satisfy $\lim x_n=L$ and $\forall n\in \Bbb N\ x_n\ge 0$, then $L\ge 0$.*

The method of proof is to suppose that $L<0$, take $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small in the defintion of the limit and obtain a contradiction. Hint: you can take $\varepsilon = \frac{|L|}{2}$.

Comment: I thought epsilon would have to be constant and couldn't have any relation to $x_n$, could you explain why this is possible?

Comment: @JohnDoe indeed, $\varepsilon$ is a constant, and it does not depend on $x_n$. It depends only on $L$.

Comment: Of course, my mistake